# Кроссплатформенность оптимизаций

Tags: c++

Существуют ли оптимизации компилятора, которые могут привести к изменению наблюдаемого поведения программы? Если да, то какие?

Comment: Возможно имеется ввиду - Неопределенное поведение (undefined behavior)

Comment: @nick_n_a согласен. А такие, которые не делают код ill-formed? Т.е. когда программа всё ещё соответствует стандарту

Comment: undefined behavior не делает код ill-formed или несоответствующим стандарту. Отмечу, что заголовок вопроса не соответствует содержимому.

Comment: @VTT почему не делает?

Comment: Если бы неопределенное поведение делало программу ill-formed, то это было бы определенное поведение. Оно также не делает программу несоответствующей стандарту, так как это поведение в стандарте не определяется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да существуют. Например Copy elision (а также, return value optimization), позволяют избавиться от вызова конструктора копирования, даже если это приводит к изменению наблюдаемого поведения.

Answer (score 1):

Существует всего 2 оптимизации, описанные в стандарте, которые это могут: [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) и [allocation elision and extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation).